# Auto generate buttons convert to labels instead of buttons

Tags: excel, vba

I have a code below which fetches data from Access database and automatically generates buttons. Now that I cannot edit CommandButtons in the sense of how they should look, I would like to turn them into lebels. So it should not generate Buttons, it should generate labels which are clickable

```
Sub UserForm1_Initialize()
    ' Connection string to the Access database
    Dim connStr As String
    connStr = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\Users\Name\Desktop\Database_App.accdb;"

    ' ADODB-connection
    Dim conn As Object
    Set conn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
    conn.Open connStr

    ' SQL query to retrieve the data
    Dim sqlQuery As String
    sqlQuery = "SELECT Feld1, Feld2 FROM ListeLink ORDER BY Feld1;" 'order by für alphabetisch

    ' Create ADODB command object
    Dim cmd As Object
    Set cmd = CreateObject("ADODB.Command")
    cmd.ActiveConnection = conn
    cmd.CommandText = sqlQuery

    ' Create ADODB recordset
    Dim rs As Object
    Set rs = cmd.Execute

    With UserForm1
        ' reverse
        Dim i As Long
        Dim buttonIndex As Long 
        buttonIndex = 1

        For i = .Controls.Count - 1 To 0 Step -1
            If TypeName(.Controls(i)) = "CommandButton" Then
                If Left(.Controls(i).Name, 7) = "Button_" Then
                    .Controls.Remove i
                End If
            End If
        Next i

        Dim topOffset As Integer
        topOffset = 2 ' start pos

        Dim myFrame As Object
        Set myFrame = .FrameButton

        Do Until rs.EOF
            ' Button generate
            Dim newButton As MSForms.CommandButton
            Set newButton = myFrame.Controls.Add("Forms.CommandButton.1", "Button_" & buttonIndex, True)

            ' Button-Set properties
            With newButton
                .Caption = rs.Fields("Feld1").Value
                .Left = 6
                .Top = topOffset
                .Width = 410
                .Height = 20
                .Tag = rs.Fields("Feld2").Value
            End With

            ReDim Preserve cmdArray(1 To buttonIndex)
            Set cmdArray(buttonIndex).CmdEvents = newButton

            Set newButton = Nothing

            ' Position 
            topOffset = topOffset + 22 ' Abstand zwischen den Buttons

            ' Next record in the recordset
            rs.MoveNext

            ' Increase the index on the count variable
            buttonIndex = buttonIndex + 1
        Loop
    End With

    ' connection close
    conn.Close
    Set conn = Nothing
End Sub
```

I've tried a few things and managed to generate labels, but I can't click them. I tried to do click event but wasn't that successful either. Can somebody help me with it? here code, where generates labels but not clickable:

```
Dim labelArray() As Object ' Deklaration des dynamischen Arrays

Sub UserForm1_Initialize()

    ' Connection string to the Access database
    Dim connStr As String
    connStr = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\Users\User\Desktop\Database_App.accdb;"

    ' Create ADODB connection
    Dim conn As Object
    Set conn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
    conn.Open connStr

    ' SQL query to retrieve the data
    Dim sqlQuery As String
    sqlQuery = "SELECT Feld1, Feld2 FROM ListeLink ORDER BY Feld1;" 'order by für alphabetisch

    ' Create ADODB command object
    Dim cmd As Object
    Set cmd = CreateObject("ADODB.Command")
    cmd.ActiveConnection = conn
    cmd.CommandText = sqlQuery

    ' Create ADODB recordset
    Dim rs As Object
    Set rs = cmd.Execute

    With UserForm1
        ' reverse
        Dim i As Long
        Dim labelIndex As Long  
        labelIndex = 1

        For i = .Controls.Count - 1 To 0 Step -1
            If TypeName(.Controls(i)) = "Label" Then
                If Left(.Controls(i).Name, 6) = "Label_" Then
                    .Controls.Remove i
                End If
            End If
        Next i

        Dim topOffset As Integer
        topOffset = 2 ' Startpos

        Dim myFrame As Object
        Set myFrame = .FrameButton

        Do Until rs.EOF
            ' Label create
            Dim newLabel As MSForms.Label
            Set newLabel = myFrame.Controls.Add("Forms.Label.1", "Label_" & labelIndex, True)

            ' Label-properties
            With newLabel
                .Caption = rs.Fields("Feld1").Value
                .Left = 6
                .Top = topOffset
                .Width = 410
                .Height = 20
                .Tag = rs.Fields("Feld2").Value
            End With

            ' Expand dynamic array
            ReDim Preserve labelArray(1 To labelIndex)
            Set labelArray(labelIndex) = newLabel

            ' Update position
            topOffset = topOffset + 22 ' Abstand zwischen den Labels

            ' Next record in the recordset
            rs.MoveNext

            ' Increase the index on the count variable
            labelIndex = labelIndex + 1
        Loop
    End With

    ' connection close
    conn.Close
    Set conn = Nothing
End Sub
```

Update:
What I want to do is like this:
[image]

Comment: Doesn't look like you're creating the same kind of "control array" as you were for the buttons?  Would help to include the event capture class you're using for the buttons/labels, and also the declarations for `cmdArray` and `labelArray`

Comment: FYI it's safer to use `With Me` to refer to the userform instance where your code is running and not (eg) `With UserForm1`

Comment: The code was in a Module, that way i used With UserForm1.

Comment: Puh its a bit complicated now i think. I dont know tbh, how can i do that... Is it the rightway, i mean i through also ListBox but cant edit each elements like a label (backgroud, hover etc) that way through it better to generate labels. Is there any better way than this?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a basic example.

Class `clsLabelEvt` to capture events from dynamically-added labels:

```vb
Option Explicit

Public WithEvents lbl As MSForms.Label
Private HoverOn As Variant 'current state

Private Sub lbl_MouseMove(ByVal Button As Integer, ByVal Shift As Integer, ByVal X As Single, ByVal Y As Single)
    HoverFormat True
End Sub

Sub HoverFormat(bOn As Boolean)
    'setting is changed, or first time being set
    If bOn <> HoverOn Or IsEmpty(HoverOn) Then
        lbl.BackColor = IIf(bOn, RGB(204, 255, 229), vbWhite)
        HoverOn = bOn
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub lbl_Click()
    MsgBox "Clicked label: '" & lbl.Name & "'   Tag: '" & lbl.tag & "'"
End Sub
```

Userform code:

```
Option Explicit

Private MyLabels As Collection 'for `clsLabelEvt` object instances
 
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    Dim lbl As MSForms.Label, i As Long
    
    Set MyLabels = New Collection
    'Add some labels
    For i = 1 To 5
        Set lbl = Me.Controls.Add("Forms.Label.1", "Label_" & i, True)
        With lbl
            .Caption = "Label " & i
            .Top = i * 20
            .Left = 20
            .Height = 15
            .Width = 40
            .tag = "Label tag " & i
        End With
        MyLabels.Add LabelEvent(lbl) '<<< set up the click/mousemove capture
    Next i
End Sub

'return an instance of `clsLabelEvt` which wraps `lbl`
Function LabelEvent(lbl As MSForms.Label) As clsLabelEvt
    Set LabelEvent = New clsLabelEvt
    Set LabelEvent.lbl = lbl
    LabelEvent.HoverFormat False 'hover off
End Function

Private Sub UserForm_MouseMove(ByVal Button As Integer, ByVal Shift As Integer, ByVal X As Single, ByVal Y As Single)
    Dim obj
    For Each obj In MyLabels 'set all labels' hover format to off
        obj.HoverFormat False
    Next obj
End Sub
```

Whether or not some other approach would be "better" really depends a lot on your exact use case/requirements.

Comment: I am currently trying to customize the code...
Yes, actually just using data from the database to generate buttons (labels) that are clickable. I have my question with an image edit, which I would like to do.

Comment: ..but Unfortunately I don't understand it and I can't get it to work. So the top "small" code is class, okay. Below? How do I add and adjust this so that it is like above and also fetches data from the access database? Maybe you could adapt it so that I - not a professional - can understand. :(

Comment: Sorry, I'm away from my computer for a while so I'm not going to be able to write a complete example including your original code.

Comment: sure, i will keep try to do this. If I get it ill write :) but could you see the picture? its possible with labels, right?

Comment: From your image what you want might be pretty complex to set up, but probably possible to do.  Edited my sample code above to merge the `click` and `mousemove` event capture.

Comment: thanks for your code and help, but couldnt implement it :( I wrote on my question my code with labels and im creating there successcully the labels, but there is no click event, can you help to add me to my code a click event?

Comment: got it!, finaly.. ill post the answer as soon as i m on my pc

Comment: Hi Tim Williams, I just added my answer code, these are only generating new labels :)

Answer (score 0):

I bit late but here im updated code for generating labels:

```
Sub UserForm1_Initialize()
    Dim labelIndex As Long 
    labelIndex = 1 
    
    Dim connStr As String
    connStr = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\here comes the link;"

' ADODB-connection creat
    Dim conn As Object
    Set conn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
    conn.Open connStr

    ' SQL-
    Dim sqlQuery As String
    sqlQuery = "SELECT Feld1, Feld2 FROM ListeLink ORDER BY Feld1;" 'order 

        ' ADODB-commandsobjekt creat
    Dim cmd As Object
    Set cmd = CreateObject("ADODB.Command")
    cmd.ActiveConnection = conn
    cmd.CommandText = sqlQuery

    ' ADODB-Recordset creat
    Dim rs As Object
    Set rs = cmd.Execute

    With UserForm1
        ' reverse
        Dim i As Long
        LabelIndex = 1

        For i = .Controls.Count - 1 To 0 Step -1
            If TypeName(.Controls(i)) = "label" Then
                If Left(.Controls(i).Name, 7) = "Label_" Then
                    .Controls.Remove i
                End If
            End If
        Next i

        Dim topOffset As Integer
        topOffset = 10 ' Startposition

        Dim myFrame As Object
        Set myFrame = .FrameButton

        ReDim labelEventsArray(1 To 1) 
        
    
    Do Until rs.EOF
        ' Label create
        Dim newLabel As MSForms.label
        Set newLabel = myFrame.Controls.Add("Forms.Label.1", "Label_" & labelIndex, True)

        ' Label-properties
        With newLabel
            .Caption = rs.Fields("Feld1").Value
            .Left = 6
            .Top = topOffset
            .Width = 410
            .Height = 20
            .Tag = rs.Fields("Feld2").Value
            .BorderStyle = fmBorderStyleSingle
            .TextAlign = fmTextAlignCenter
            .FontSize = 10
            .FontName = "Calibri"
            Set labelEventsArray(labelIndex).LabelEvents = newLabel

        End With

        ' Create instance of Klasse1
        Set labelEventsArray(labelIndex) = New Klasse1

        ' Link Klasse1 to the newLabel
        Set labelEventsArray(labelIndex).LabelEvents = newLabel
        

        ' Expand dynamic array
        ReDim Preserve labelEventsArray(1 To labelIndex + 1)

        ' Expand dynamic array for labels (optional)
        ReDim Preserve labelArray(1 To labelIndex)
        Set labelArray(labelIndex) = newLabel

        ' Update position
        topOffset = topOffset + 22

        ' Next record in the recordset
        rs.MoveNext

        ' Increase the index on the count variable
        labelIndex = labelIndex + 1
        Loop
    End With

    ' close
    conn.Close
    Set conn = Nothing
    
   
    
End Sub
```